# Return all ages that are ints

Tags: mongodb

I'm studying Mongo and trying out it's features. I have a collection that has documents with name and age. The age is normally a number, but sometimes it can be a string, example:

```
{
name: "example",
age: 20 
}

{
name: "exampleTwo",
age: "Not informed"
}

{
name: "exampleThree",
age: 21
}
```

I know that i can, and probably should, insert default number such as -1 or 0 for non-informed ages but i'm trying out and testing mongo Features. In this case, having Documents with different types in the same collection.

So i would like to make a query that returns all Documents that has age as the type of a number. For this specific example i know i can use the query:

```
db.example.find({age: { $ne: "Not Informed" }})
```

But i was wondering if  it's possible to make a less specific query, as mentioned before, one that returns all documents that has the age as a Number? Checking the type of the value instead of the value itself?

Comment: That's what [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) queries are for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Changed in version 3.2: $type operator accepts string aliases for the BSON types in addition to the numbers corresponding to the BSON types."](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#available-types)

Hence, this always works:

```
db.example.find( { age : { $type : 16 } } )
```

This works since Mongo 3.2:

```
db.example.find( { age : { $type : 'int' } } )
```